# Haxe convert fnt to bfnt?

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel, haxelib

can you guide me to convert fnt font to bfnt? i just want to create 1 bfnt font to make game mod. Hope everybody help please.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhom9.png)

I tried installing haxe and creating projects in flixel but don't know how to convert bfnt, i don't know much about code.